# How to remote access and send my fingerprint

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-access, fingerprint

I'm currently using TeamViewer to access a computer from a different network, I'm working at home and the computer is in my office work.

The problem is I'm using software and I need to scan my fingerprint to do the transaction which is failed to do so in TeamViewer.

Basically, I need to send my fingerprint on it when it ask for it. Is that possible?

Comment: If the remote PC is running Pro or Enterprise flavor I would prefer RDP instead of TeamViewer. RDP allows forwarding of local USB devices and other resources like smartcards, therefore fingerprint may also work.

Comment: @Robert - RDP is Remote Desktop Connection right?

Comment: Yes, RDP is Remote Desktop Connection which is available in Pro and Enterprise versions of Windows for single user remote access.